# Android application to web server with JSON lib

Tags: java, php, android, json

i have a problem which i cant solve for days.

the String line input is "{"name":"John", "Hobby":"Cycle"}" sent from a JSON from PHP server

The code at android application

```
public void testFn()
{
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String tmp = gson.toJson(line.toString());
            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(tmp);
            sb.append(jobj.get(1).toString() + "\n");
        }
    }catch ....
}
```

i wanted to convert the string received and convert it to a JSONObject / JSONArray which i can retrieve it or display to TextView as a String format. but i keep getting the error of CastException from java.String to JSON.simple.JSONObject..
Hope someone could enlighten me on this

Comment: No comment, no response. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I don't know, without studying anything about JSON, how you can ask any question here? I will highly recommend you to read http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp. I don't think you have good knowledge about JSON first. Because, arrays are declared between `[]` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String str = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"Hobby\":\"Cycle\"}";
//i wrote preceded "\" to very " because it is code format string, 
//not came from internet. You can pass direct response from PHP server
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
    Log.d("Home",json.getString("name"));
    Log.d("Home",json.getString("Hobby"));
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Basically now i edited my code where my<br/>
    String line = "{"name":"John","Hobby":"Cycle"}";<br/>
    Object obj=parser.parse(line);<br/>
    JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;<br/>
    String tmp = array.getString(1); <-- I get a CastException

Comment: @user2504530, it is but obvious cast exception because you are converting object to array. read what i gave in comment. then come back with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyJsonObject{
  private String name;
  private String Hobby;
  MyJsonObject() {

  }
}

MyJsonObject obj = new MyJsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

(Deserialization)

```
MyJsonObject obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyJsonObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically now i edited my code here

```
String line = "{"name":"John","Hobby":"Cycle"}";
Object obj=parser.parse(line);
JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject)array.get(0);
System.out.println(obj2.get("name").toString());
```

sorry i figured out a way.

```
Output:
John
```